# Must a function in lambda-calculus which inputs a boolean function be defined in a certian way?

Tags: proof-techniques, lambda-calculus

This question is my best attempt to get at a more general question about what one can get from terms in the lambda calculus.

Using the church encoding, we define booleans by
$\texttt{true} = \lambda x,y.x$ and $\texttt{false} = \lambda x,y.y$

Define the set of terms $Bool = \{\texttt{true}, \texttt{false}\}$, and 
let $Bool \to Bool = \{g \; | \; \text{if } b \in Bool \text{ then } g \; b \in Bool\}$

Let $f$ be a term with the property that if $g \in Bool \to Bool$ then $f \; g$ normalizes to a boolean.

Intuitively, I believe $f$ can be either a constant function or it can use $g$. Precisely:
**Is it true that any such f satisfies one of the following properties:**

- There exists some term $b \in Bool$ so that for any $g \in Bool \to Bool$, $f \; g = b $
- There exists some term $b \in Bool$ so that for any $g \in Bool \to Bool$, $f \; g = g \; b $
- There exists some term $b \in Bool$ so that for any $g \in Bool \to Bool$, $f \; g = not (g \; b) $
- EDIT: as Derik points out, the above three cases only capture 6 of the 16 set-theoretic functions of type (Bool -> Bool) -> Bool. The point was can $f$ be defined in a way other than those set theoretic ones.

(where $a = b$ means that $a$ normalizes to $b$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we assume that $g$ normalizes when applied to any Boolean input, then we can apply it to `true` and `false`, and then we can can compute any Boolean function of those two values. That is, we can readily produce all $16$ possible set theoretic functions, $2^{2^2}$. Your schemas only cover $6$ of those.

But the story goes further, your definition of $f\in(Bool\to Bool)\to Bool$ does *not* require that $f$ only apply its argument to Booleans. Similarly, $g\in Bool\to Bool$ does not restrict $g$'s behavior for all other inputs. At this point, there are all kinds of additional possibilities (even when restricting to $Bool\to Bool$ inputs) where $f$ applies its argument to other things and performs some other calculation to ultimately produce a Boolean. So there are many other potential terms. If you want tighter guarantees, you may want to consider looking at typed lambda calculi.

(As a tangent, but an interesting tangent, is the class of [sequentially realizable functionals](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0168-0072(01)00110-5). These include functions which are mathematical functions but which aren't implementable in a "pure" way, i.e. they require things like exceptions or mutable state to be implemented.)

Comment: Thanks, but how is it possible to apply g to something not a boolean, and somehow get a boolean from that value? g applied to non-booleans can be any sort of output. This was the point of my question, even though I feel silly for missing 10 of the 16 set theoretic ones.

Comment: I think that a better question for me to have asked originally is "can I make a function f such that for any x, (f x) is a boolean other than the constant functions?"